# Problemas ao decodificar assembly x86 a partir do binário

Tags: assembly, x86, intel

Tenho escrito um programa cujo objetivo é ler um arquivo executável binário compilado para a arquitetura x86 (intel) e interpretar o código assembly ali contido executando-o instrução por instrução. A parte de ler o executável, extrair as seções e criar uma memória virtual que inclui o código executável funciona sem problemas e pude executar alguns programas bem simples (exemplo: `int main() {return 0;}`).

Para decodificar as instruções estou me baseando no [manual da intel](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html) (em inglês). Adicionalmente estou usando o utilitário [`objdump -d`](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/objdump.html) para exibir o disassembly do executável para comparar com os meus resultados.

Meu problema está em decodificar a seguinte sequência de bytes: (hexadecimal)

```
67 89 04 18
```

O `objdump` afirma corretamente que isso significa:

```
mov    %eax, (%eax, %ebx, 1)
```

Meu problema está quando faço o processo manualmente tomando por base o manual:

1. **`67`**: Prefixo de alteração do tamanho do endereço;
2. **`89`**: Opcode da instrução `mov` de um registro para uma memória/registro;
3. **`04`**: Byte do ModR/M para indicar que o primeiro argumento é `%eax`, a necessidade de um SIB e que o *displacement* é zero;
4. **`18`**: Byte do SIB indicando que o último argumento é `%eax+%ebx`.

O detalhe é que ambos o ModR/M e o SIB são considerados em 32-bits. Significa que neste estágio o tamanho do operando e o tamanho do endereço são 32-bits. No entanto o prefixo de alteração do tamanho de endereço precisou ser utilizado, o que significa que a instrução original (sem o prefixo) é de 32-bits no operando e 16-bits no endereço. Isto está correto?

Como é possível existir uma instrução com operandos e 32-bits e endereçamento de 16-bits? Tentei compilar um código com uma instrução assim usando o `gas` (GNU Assembler) e ele retorna um erro afirmando que aquela combinação é impossível. Por que então é o padrão?

Comment: Uma pergunta simples: Que tipo de programa C quando compilado gera a sequência `67 89 04 18`? Quando você executa este programa, o que esta instrução faz quando tem endereços e registradores cujos valores não cabem em 16 bits?

Comment: Um pode pode gerar uma instrução bastante semelhante: `int main() { volatile int a[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; volatile int i = 2; a[i] = i; }`. Produz essa ao compilar com o `gcc -O3`: `mov %edx, 8(%esp, %eax, 4)`. Bastante semelhante ao exemplo que usei.

Comment: Curiosamente essa é codificada como `89 54 84 08`. Não usou nenhum prefixo. Agora estou confuso... Por que um caso requer o prefixo e o outro não?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O [manual da Intel](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-vol-2a-manual.pdf), na seção 2.1.1 afirma que o prefixo 67H permite que programas mudem o endereçamento entre 16 e 32 bits. Que qualquer tamanho pode ser o padrão, e que o prefixo seleciona o não-padrão:

> The address-size override prefix (67H) allows programs to switch
>   between 16- and 32-bit addressing. Either size can be the default; the
>   prefix selects the non-default size.

O prefixo muda o endereçamento, olhe as tabelas 2-1 e 2-2 da seção 2.1.5.

Por exemplo, uma instrução sem prefixo poderia ser `MOV [EBX], ESP` e adicionando o prefixo se tornaria `MOV [BP+DI], ESP`.

Comment: Sim, isso eu escrevi na pergunta. A dúvida é: por que `mov %eax, (%eax, %ebx, 1)` precisa do prefixo e `mov %edx, 8(%esp, %eax, 4)` não? Qual a diferença?

Comment: Após a edição. De fato, esse é o comportamento que observei na maior parte dos casos e que entendo ser o certo. Mas por que `MOV [EAX+EBX], EAX` tem o prefixo?

Comment: Que eu saiba, não se pode usar SIB com endereçamento 16 bits. Isso quer dizer que o programa está executando com 16 bits de endereçamento por padrão, e o prefixo serve para entrar em modo 32 bits.

Comment: Eu fiz alguns testes a mais e não consegui reproduzir o meu problema. Provavelmente eu tinha feito algo errado na hora de interpretar os dados. O prefixo `67` não aparece para o exemplo da pergunta agora. De qualquer forma, aceitarei sua resposta, obrigado.